# Trying to unbrick a router using Ubuntu

Tags: ethernet, router

I'm trying to unbrick my Buffalo WZR-HP-G300NH that had OpenWRT on it (it bricked when I tried to go back to stock.) Windows fixes didn't work so I am trying an Ubuntu 17.10 Live USB, but I am running into problems and don't know much about Linux so I'm stuck

These are the instructions I am following:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install tftp-hpa
sudo /etc/init.d/networking stop
sudo ifconfig eth0 192.168.11.2
sudo ifconfig eth0 netmask 255.255.255.0
sudo arp -s 192.168.11.1 00:1D:12:34:56:78
#change to the folder where you put the firmware image, if it's on desktop then it's
#"/home/ubuntu/Desktop".
cd /home/ubuntu/Desktop
tftp 192.168.11.1
*from this point, you're under tftp command prompt, the "tftp>" is the prompt tftp gives you, you just need to type the command AFTER that.
tftp> verbose
tftp> binary
tftp> trace
tftp> rexmt 1
tftp> timeout 60
tftp> put wzrg300nh-firmware.tftp
```

and I'm getting stuck at `sudo ifconfig eth0 192.168.11.2` because it says

```
eth0: error fetching interface information: Device not found
```

I tried the same step with eth1, eth2, etc but it can't find it. I do have internet connection so I know the Ethernet card works

edit: apparently this got flagged because it wasn't specific enough. I guess my question was how to find what my version of eth0 was and chilli555's answer was what worked for me, it turned out to be enp1s0 and I managed to unbrick my router as a result, so thanks!

Comment: try entering the command `ip link show`  (or alternatives `ip addr`, `ifconfig`...) to get your interface name

Comment: In 17.10, the interface name is not eth0, it is likely enp2s0 or similar. Substitute the correct interface name and proceed.

Comment: E.g. `ifconfig` lists the devices with their names.